# 'Add Item' button in VSCode Extension settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm adding `configuration` contribution point for my VSCode extension.
What I'd like to achieve is to have graphical 'Add Item' editor just like for CSS Custom data section, as shown on picture below.

[image]

[Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points) appears to mention types `number`, `string`, `boolean` that can be edited directly in Settings UI.
Is there a way to have this editor with Add Item button for my own configuration section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the editor for string arrays. It was added in the [1.37 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_settings-editor-support-for-string-arrays) (July 2019).

Here's an example setting definition:

```json
"configuration": {
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "default": ["a", "b", "c"]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that there currently doesn't seem to be any support for arrays of types other than `string`.